# brushless motor overheating when connected to l298n motor driver

Tags: dc-motor

I am using a brushless motor such as [this](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/oj0AAOSwubRXGOgf/s-l1600.jpg) one and am trying to drive it in both directions using a [l298n mini](http://www.robotpark.com/Mini-L298N-Motor-Driver) motor driver. However, when connecting the motor to the board and the board to the 5v output of the rapsberry pi 4, the motor becomes massively hot, to a degree where you burn yourself when touching it, even when you are not moving the motor at all. I replaced both the motor and the board to make sure it's not an isolated issue. is there a way to prevent this problem from occuring?

Comment: Your motor photo says 3.7V, is that the actual motor spec, if so don't feed it more than that.

Comment: the issue still occurs when connected to the 3.3v output